# Deploy .NET C# WinForm Project onto another computer

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I recently wanted to test my application on another computer that has the latest .NET framework (I'm developing in 4) but without Visual Studio. I heard I had to "deploy" my project onto the other computer, which includes all the crystal report dll's and databases. Is there a program out there that would allow me to create an installation wizard to get all the project's dependencies and install them on another computer? The question may be very confusing but please ask a question and I will try to give you an answer. THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), even if you don't go with this for your final installation route it will give you a quick way of getting your program onto other machines for testing.

You access it from **Build > Publish [Application Name]**

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering, I have tried to publish my project, but when i tried to install it, I get this error    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807993/winform-deployment-error  thanks

Comment: Right solution had to fix a few answers but worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio deployment project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317(v=vs.90).aspx